# Why doesn'n create pdf-documents in java servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, pdf-generation, itext, pdfbox

I use iText/Pdfbox to create a PDF document. Everything works when I create the PDF using a standalone Java class like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
...
...
...
}
```

The document is created correctly.

But I need create a PDF document from a Servlet. I paste the code into the get or post method, run that servlet on the server, but the PDF document isn't created!

This code works as a standalone application:

[image]

This code doesn't work:

[image]

Comment: Add the code as text, not as screenshot

Comment: What means `doesn't work`? Any exception?

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: First choose the technology: either this is a PdfBox question or it's an iText question. You are using PdfBox code, so your question shouldn't be tagged as an iText question. Note that iText code is usually easier to read than PdfBox code. Nevertheless, I did the effort trying to read your PdfBox code. I see that you create a file on the file system. Why are you doing that? You don't send anything to the `response` object. This means that your code *shouldn't work* and you *shouldn't be surprised* that it doesn't work.

Comment: I mean that the code is not saved on disk.I want save pdf on my hard drive.

Comment: I want save pdf on my hard drive automaticly by servlets.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the documentation. For instance the answer to the question [How can I serve a PDF to a browser without storing a file on the server side?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-can-i-serve-pdf-browser-without-storing-file-server-side)

You are currently creating a file on your file system. You aren't using the `response` object, meaning you aren't sending any bytes to the browser. This explains why nothing happens in the browser.

This is a simple example:

```
public class Hello extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        try {
            // step 1
            Document document = new Document();
            // step 2
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, response.getOutputStream());
            // step 3
            document.open();
            // step 4
            document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World"));
            document.add(new Paragraph(new Date().toString()));
            // step 5
            document.close();
        } catch (DocumentException de) {
            throw new IOException(de.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

However, some browsers experience problems when you send bytes directly like this. It's safer to create the file in memory using a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and to tell the browser how many bytes it can expect in the content header:

```
public class PdfServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            // Get the text that will be added to the PDF
            String text = request.getParameter("text");
            if (text == null || text.trim().length() == 0) {
                 text = "You didn't enter any text.";
            }
            // step 1
            Document document = new Document();
            // step 2
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);
            // step 3
            document.open();
            // step 4
            document.add(new Paragraph(String.format(
                "You have submitted the following text using the %s method:",
                request.getMethod())));
            document.add(new Paragraph(text));
            // step 5
            document.close();

            // setting some response headers
            response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
            response.setHeader("Cache-Control",
                "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
            response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
            // setting the content type
            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            // the contentlength
            response.setContentLength(baos.size());
            // write ByteArrayOutputStream to the ServletOutputStream
            OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
            baos.writeTo(os);
            os.flush();
            os.close();
        }
        catch(DocumentException e) {
            throw new IOException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

For the full source code, see [PdfServlet](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-9#377-pdfservlet.java). You can try the code here: http://demo.itextsupport.com/book/

You wrote in a comment

> This demo writes the PDF file into the browser. I want to save the PDF on my hard drive.

This question could be interpreted in two different ways:

1. You want to write the file to a specific directory on the user's disk drive without any user interaction. This is **forbidden**! It would be a serious security hazard if a server could force a file to be written anywhere on a user's disk drive.
2. You want to show a dialog box so that the user can save the PDF on his disk drive in a directory of his choice instead of just showing the PDF in the browser. In this case, please take a closer look at the documentation. You'll see this line: `response.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment;filename="+ "testPDF.pdf");` You can set the `Content-disposition` to `inline` if you want the PDF to open in the browser, but in the question, the `Content-disposition` is set to `attachment` which triggers a dialog box to open.

See also [How to show a Save As dialog for a iText generated PDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978165/how-to-show-a-save-as-dialog-for-a-itext-generated-pdf)

Comment: http://demo.itextsupport.com/book/ This demo write pdf into the browser .I want save pdf on my hard drive.

Comment: I'll update my answer because your question could be interpreted in different ways. (You need to learn how to ask questions more accurately.)

Comment: Yes, i need as the result standard dialog box that asks the user what he wants to just showing the PDF in the browser or saved to the file system(zip).

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. But i havn't know yet, how convert pdf to zip and get standard dialog box that asks the user what he wants to just showing the PDF in the browser or saved to the file system in zip-forma?.

Comment: There is no *standard* dialog box to do this. You need to know what the user wants *before* sending the response. This would require telepathy or magic. Please ask questions in a more scientific way. For instance: post a new question asking how to serve a ZIP file containing a PDF document. Do not use the comment section to post follow-up questions. Do not expect an answer if you don't accept correct answers.

Comment: With three down-votes, you are lucky that I even bothered helping you. Please follow the rules of StackOverflow or you might be left with no one wanting to help you.